# Is it possible to detect if a socket is in the CLOSE_WAIT state?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I am using a `TcpClient` object to send and receive data. When a client loses its connection, I can see by using TcpView that its associated connection is in a `CLOSE_WAIT` state. Is it possible in c# to see the state of a socket? I simply want to detect the `CLOSE_WAIT` state so I can close the socket on the server end. I understand that I can wait to receive bytes for a certain amount of time and then close the connection if nothing is received. I just would rather close the socket and its thread immediately. Is the socket's state able to be detected on the c# side? The TcpView program can determine this. Can a c# program do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but if you check [`socket.Available`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.available%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it'll throw a `SocketException`.  You still need to check the reason, though.

Also not ideal, because it's a bit clunky, is to call [`Poll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.poll%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (with `SelectRead`).  If it returns `true`, either there's data to read or the connection is closed.  If there's no data to read, then that's your answer.

Comment: Thanks. My current clunky solution is to simply try to send one byte to the client and catch the socket exception if the client has disconnected. I just don't want to rely on exceptions to end a session. Using Poll() with SelectWrite might actually be a better way of what I'm doing. Still, I would like to be able to check the tcp status (established, close_wait, etc) for the socket. I'm trying to somehow get a TcpConnectionInformation object that corresponds to the socket at hand, but have not figured it out if it's possible.

Comment: Poll() with SelectWrite still returns true if the connection is in the close_wait state. I can't use SelectRead because the client may not have sent its message yet.

Comment: I'll look into the `TcpConnectionInformation` thing later, hopefully; you're right that just knowing the status would be clearer. `SelectRead` is definitely the way to go, though, because it tells you if there's something going on _to_ read. The follow-up condition (trying to read more data) tells you whether it's data or a closed connection. Like I said, not ideal...

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to understand how to implement this check with poll() and SelectRead. If the client has not yet sent a message, then there is no data to read, but that doesn't mean the client has disconnected. It may still be working on something before sending.

Comment: Sorry, sorry. If there's no data to read (and the connection is good), `Poll()` returns `false`. I should have made that clearer in the first place. In the lower-level APIs (`socket.h` in C), you talk about "read activity," here, so it's obvious.